# Added SplitViewController and thread never gets to viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having trouble finding why I never get to viewDidLoad since I added my SplitViewController.

This is with iOS 5, and my storyboard looks like this:

```
                 TabBarCtroller   -> Nav Ctrlr  -> TableView
                                \
             ^                   v 
->DetailVC  /                     --> Nav Ctrolr ->  TableView

             \-> UIImageView
```

Everything worked fine before I added the DetailVC and TabBarController.

I have this running for iPhone fine but not iPad.  I put breakpoints in every method, and it doesn't get to viewDidLoad like my iPhone version does.  The simulator brings up the iPad, but it's a blank white view with no table shown, not even a blank table.

The relationship from the DetailVC to TabBarCtroller is the main one and the lower one is the secondary relationship.  Everything else is a straightforward relationship.  It's after the tableViews that I get into segue's.

Any ideas?  I've searched for the answer on the internet but only found iOS 4 comments that deal with files I don't have to deal with in iOS 5.

Here's code for splitview:

```
- (void)updateSplitViewDetail { 
    id detail = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    if([detail isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]])
    { 
         MapViewController *mapVC = (MapViewController *)detail;
         mapVC.delegate = self;
         mapVC.annotations = [self mapAnnotations];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what I did to fix this a couple of days ago, but it's working now.  Thanks anyway!